# Inserting an fprintf() into this loop causes it to loop infinitely. Why?

Tags: c

I have this loop that parses machine code and emulates the instructions as if it were a processor. If at any point I try to access a memory location that is beyond what the program defines as the size of memory (1MB), it will print an error saying that I'm out of range.

This is a school assignment, so all of the input binaries should work correctly if my code is correct. But on one of the binaries, I have an error stating that I'm trying to access memory outside this range. So I want to put an `fprintf()` (or just `printf()`, it doesn't matter) statement in there to see the contents of some of my variables. However, when I do this, I get completely different behavior. I never get this message and instead the program loops infinitely. I'm not changing anything else. And it seems that it doesn't matter what I print. Inserting `printf("hello")` causes the same behavior.

If I put my `fprintf()` inside the function that prints the error, I don't get the infinite loop and everything prints as I would expect.

It's a fairly large and complex program, so I can't just paste it in here and I don't think just a small portion will suffice, so I hope I've provided enough information to get help.

I am putting newlines at the end of my statements as I've read that is supposed to flush the buffer, but even if I add `fflush(stdout)`, it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a memory corruption fault, buffer overun or even a stack crash.  Unfortunatly these rarely showup where the fault is but later on when something else uses the memory and can be really hard to locate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information you've been able to supply, it sounds like your program is exhibiting *undefined behaviour*. Undefined behaviour doesn't necessarily mean that the program will crash, it could appear to work correctly. Until you change something else, like adding an `fprintf()` somewhere, then it might fail.

You might want to try running your program under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help catch memory-related errors. Also, turn up the warning level on your compiler *all the way* and fix everything it finds.

Static analysers such as [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) and the [Clang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/index.html) are also helpful.

Comment: It looks like this was the correct answer. I still don't know why printing something was causing the infinite loop, but what I found was that on jump-and-link instructions, I was incorrectly calculating the function return address and therefore skipping one instruction every time I returned from  a function call. So I must have been corrupting memory somewhere. It's my suspicion that the `*printf()` functions ended up using some memory that I was happily overwriting and then skipping an instruction on each function return caused me to miss a loop counter incrementer.